# Put parameters of a function with for loop from list

Tags: python, for-loop, data-analysis

The list:

```
li=['check3_dwg_Polyline', 'check2_dwg_Polyline', 
    'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg',# this will not be needed to extracted
    'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg',# >> >>
    'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line', 
    'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line']
```

**Purpose**

Put the parameters as this:

```
erase('check3_dwg_Polyline','check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line','output_name')
```

**Useful info: tried sorting the list but didn't fix it.**

---

The purpose is to extract the files from the list and put them in the function `erase` through a loop.

Like this:

```
erase('check3_dwg_Polyline','check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line','output_name')
```

I tried:

```
a=[li[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(li), 3)]

for base, base_f, base_line in a:
    print(base, base_line, base + "_output") # when it is fixed the 
                                             # print will be replaced with 
                                              # 'erase' to form the function
```

and it gives:

```
check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg  check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line  check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_output 
check3_dwg_Polyline  check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg  check3_dwg_Polyline_output
```

while it should:

```
check3_dwg_Polyline   check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line  check3_dwg_Polyline_output

check2_dwg_Polyline   check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line  check2_dwg_Polyline_output
```

so later it can be put to function like this:

```
erase('check3_dwg_Polyline','check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line','output_name')
```

Comment: You need to explain what this code is supposed to do and what it is currently doing wrong.

Comment: It is still unclear what you want. Can you show us your expected output and current output/error?

Comment: @FHTMitchell can you suggest how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the function `erase` with the first 3 items of `li`, you would slice off the first 3 items of the list and call the function with `apply`:

```
def erase(a,b,c):
    #do something with a,b,c
    return

li=['check3_dwg_Polyline', 'check2_dwg_Polyline', 
'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg',
'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg',
'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line', 
'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line']

apply(erase,li[:3])
```